# Is there a way to check if "increase contrast" is enabled in the accessibility settings in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, uiaccessibility

On iOS 7.0.3 turning on increased contrast mode removes the blur effects you'd normally see in the nav bar if you're using a bar tint color with an alpha less than 1.0, which makes the nav bar seem much more transparent than it is with the default settings.

Is there a way to programmatically check to see if this setting is enabled? While UIAccessibility has a ton of other functions like UIAccessibilityIsInvertColorsEnabled(), I can't find anything related to this setting specifically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently there's no public API for checking whether that option is on.

According to the [UIKit Function Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning), the only checks you can perform are the following

- `UIAccessibilityPostNotification`
- `UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning`
- `UIAccessibilityIsClosedCaptioningEnabled`
- `UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession`
- `UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled`
- `UIAccessibilityIsInvertColorsEnabled`
- `UIAccessibilityIsMonoAudioEnabled`
- `UIAccessibilityZoomFocusChanged`
- `UIAccessibilityRegisterGestureConflictWithZoom`
- `UIAccessibilityConvertFrameToScreenCoordinates`
- `UIAccessibilityConvertPathToScreenCoordinates`

Comment: This answer is now out of date, as pointed out by dave in his answer iOS 8 brought in the ability to check with UIAccessibilityDarkerSystemColorsEnabled()

Answer (score 13):

As of iOS 8 there is a way to check:

```
UIKIT_EXTERN BOOL UIAccessibilityDarkerSystemColorsEnabled() NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

as of modern iOS:

UIAccessibility.isDarkerSystemColorsEnabled

Answer (score 4):

For iOS 13 and above we can use `accessibilityContrast`

**Documentation**

> Use this trait to determine whether the user requested a high contrast
> between foreground and background content. The user sets the contrast
> level in the Accessibility area in Settings.

[Apple doc link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection/3238079-accessibilitycontrast)

Answer (score 0):

As Anshad mentioned, since iOS13 it is indeed possible, here's the code:

```
UITraitCollection.current.accessibilityContrast == .high
```